# Create an int column in ListView (Winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to create an integer (or DataTime, etc) column in ListView? It is quite important, because I would like to properly sort the list according to this column.

The only way to add subItems to a ListViewItem I found are:

```
listviewitem.SubItems.Add("1");
```

I would like to avoid parsing these strings to get the int representation for every sort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Tag property.  These little helper functions take care of it:

```
private void setListItem(int row, int column, int value) {
  ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem item = listView1.Items[row].SubItems[column];
  item.Tag = value;
  item.Text = value.ToString();
}
private int getListItem(int row, int column) {
  return (int)listView1.Items[row].SubItems[column].Tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than that you just add strings to the list and receive strings by using `.Text` property.

Example:

```
int a = 0;
listView1.Items.Add(a.ToString());
```

or

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Items[0].SubItems[0].Text);
```

You can do this same with `DataTime` and other datatypes, just by converting them to `String` type.

How you interpret the column containing i.e dates it fully depends of you.
Just implement your algorithm of sorting particular `ListView` column.

Comment: As far as I know a particular ListView column doesn't support different data types you can than sort by some already implemented function. You just do it yourself by implementing specific soft-algorithm for a particular column...

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a column of type integer like what we have the columns in datagrid, actually i do not have idea about listview  control. Let me know if you find the answer.

Comment: ListView is different from data grid view in this respect, you can have only strings. So you need to use the tag property (I have just accepted the correct answer)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link:
[How to sort a ListView control by a column in Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319401)

Then for function `Compare`:
(add the following switch case as per your requirement of datatype  in respect to column datatype)

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    //(...)
    switch (ColumnToSort)
    {
        case 2:
            compareResult = objectComparer.Compare(DateTime.Parse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text), DateTime.Parse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text));
            break;
        case 3:
            compareResult = objectComparer.Compare(float.Parse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text.Replace("kb", "").Replace("mb", "")), float.Parse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text.Replace("kb", "").Replace("mb", "")));
            break;

        default:
            compareResult = objectComparer.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
            break;
    }
    //(...)
}
```